# fixedSize button não estar funcionando no flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Estou tendo problema com o tamanho do botão, toda vez que eu coloco uma palavra maior do que o botão, o botao aumenta junto, gostaria de deixar o tamanho do botão fixo, pesquisei e descobrir que o **fixedSize** faz justamente oque estou querendo porém na hora que coloco ele no código, ele dar **comando inexistente**, gostaria de saber oque estou fazendo de errado ou se na versão mais nova do flutter eles trocaram o comando por outro nome.

Meu codigo atual:

```
 TextButton(
                    onPressed: decrement,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)

                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "test",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),

                    ),
```

No caso pelo oque pesquisei no lugar do padding deveria ser **fixedSize: Size(20, 20)** mas não estar funcionando.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta da seguinte forma:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: decrement,
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    fixedSize: Size(20.0, 20.0),
  ),
  child: Text(
    "test",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 10,
    ),
  ),
);
```